# Where are some implementations in <type_traits> header file?

Tags: c++

I saw some implementation in <type_traits> header file, but there are some implementations that I could not find, like this:

```
// STRUCT TEMPLATE is_class
template <class _Ty>
struct is_class : bool_constant<__is_class(_Ty)> {}; // determine whether _Ty is a class

template <class _Ty>
_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool is_class_v = __is_class(_Ty);
```

I would like to know the implementation of __is_class.
Does somebody know where the implementation is? I use the IDE named visual studio 2019.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with VS, but I suspect that `__is_class` is a builtin recognized by the compiler which has no C++ definition. It appears to be documented on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/compiler-support-for-type-traits-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160) in MS compiler's docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These symbols refer to reserved, built-in tokens that are recognized and evaluated ***by the compiler itself***. The compiler knows what `__is_class` means, evaluates it for the given type, and then uses the results of the evaluation.

It just so happens that gcc nicely documents its built-in symbols [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Type-Traits.html#Type-Traits) (this is for gcc 10.2, other versions of gcc have pretty much the same page). EDIT: [here's the same page for VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/compiler-support-for-type-traits-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160) -- pretty much the same thing, from the looks of it.

On that page, somewhere you will happen to find your `__is_class` function defined, for gcc. Other compilers tend to make things work the same way, perhaps varying only in the names of the symbols themselves.

To summarize, you won't find `__is_class`, and others, formally defined in any header file. These functions, classes, et. al. are baked into the compiler itself.

Comment: The OP mentioned that they are using VS2019, so [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/compiler-support-for-type-traits-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160) might be a more relevant link for the relevant builtin symbols.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be pretty much the same thing, mostly...